Evaluation of NO2 extraction code
I have two blocks of NO2 extraction code but they give different results. I can't figure out why and I'm not sure which one is correct. How do I determine this?
First code:
// Import the example feature collection.
var dataset = ee.FeatureCollection('FAO/GAUL/2015/level1');

var ROI = dataset.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Sliven'));

var no2Raw = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/OFFL/L3_NO2');

function maskClouds(image) {
  var cf = image.select('cloud_fraction');
  var mask = cf.lte(0.2); 
  return image.updateMask(mask).copyProperties(image);
} 

var no2 = no2Raw
  .filterBounds(ROI)
  .map(maskClouds)
  .select('NO2_column_number_density')
  .map(function(image){
    //micromol/m2
    return image.multiply(1e6)
                .set(image.toDictionary(image.propertyNames()))
  });

function getMonthlyMean(collectionLabel, img) {
  return function(img) {
    var no2Mean = img.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      geometry: ROI.geometry(),
      scale: 1000
    }).get('NO2_column_number_density');
    
    // Get the month of the image.
    var month = img.date().get('month');
    
    // Return a feature with monthly NO2 concentration and month properties.
    return ee.Feature(null, {
      'conc': no2Mean,
      'Month': month,
      'type': collectionLabel
    });
  };
} 

var startDate = '2019-01-01';
var endDate = '2019-12-31';

var monthlyNO2 = no2
  .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
  .map(getMonthlyMean('NO2', no2));
  
var monthlyMeanNO2 = ee.FeatureCollection(
  ee.List.sequence(1, 12).map(function(month){
    var monthlyData = monthlyNO2.filter(ee.Filter.eq('Month', month));
    var meanNO2 = monthlyData.aggregate_mean('conc');
    return ee.Feature(null, {
      'conc': meanNO2,
      'Month': month
    });
  })
);
// Make a chart.
var chart = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(
  monthlyMeanNO2, 'Month', 'conc')
  .setChartType('LineChart')
  .setOptions({
    title: 'Monthly Mean [NO2] during selected dates',
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Month'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: '[NO2] (micromol/m2)'
    }
  });

// Print it to the console.
print('Monthly Mean NO2 for the study region', chart);

Second code:
var dataset = ee.FeatureCollection('FAO/GAUL/2015/level1');
// Import the example feature collection.
var ROI = dataset.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Sliven'));

var startYear = 2019;
var endYear = 2020;

function maskClouds(image) {
  var cf = image.select('cloud_fraction');
  var mask = cf.lte(0.2); 
  return image.updateMask(mask).copyProperties(image);
}
var features = []; 

for (var month = 1; month <= 12; month++) {
  var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(startYear, month, 1);
  var endDate = startDate.advance(1, 'month');

  var data = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S5P/OFFL/L3_NO2")
             .map(maskClouds)
             .select('NO2_column_number_density')
             .filterDate(startDate, endDate);

  var ortalama_NO2 = data.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean());
  var alan = ortalama_NO2.clip(ROI);
  
  var stats = alan.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: ROI.geometry(),
    scale: 1000
  });

  var NO2_mean = stats.get('NO2_column_number_density_mean');

  var NO2_mean_ug_m3 = ee.Number(NO2_mean).multiply(1e6);

  var feature = ee.Feature(null, {
    'Date': startDate.format('YYYY-MM'),
    'NO2_mean': NO2_mean_ug_m3
  });

  features.push(feature); 
}

var featureCollection = ee.FeatureCollection(features);

var chart = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(featureCollection, 'Date', 'NO2_mean')
  .setChartType('LineChart')
  .setOptions({
    title: 'Mean NO2',
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Date'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Mean NO2 (µg/m³)'
    }
  });

print(chart);

